# How many different numbers can you make with the following digits?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different numbers can you make with the following eight digits?

$1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0$

The problem I encounter is how to include numbers that aren't 8 digits long? For instance the number 12.

I know the answer for 8 digit numbers (assuming zero can be a starting digit):

$\frac{8!}{2!3!2!}$

But I can't seem to figure out how to include all the other numbers that aren't 8 digits long.

Comment: Maybe when the question says "with the following 8 digits" it means you have to use all 8 digits, and therefore, your answer is correct.

Comment: @JLee, it's not, we were told to consider all possible numbers not only the 8 digit ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it.

Count all of the one-digit numbers.  Count all of the two-digit numbers.  Rinse and repeat until you've counted all of the eight-digit numbers.

You'll want to determine up-front whether $0012, 012,$ and $12$ are the same numbers, or different numbers.

There are obviously $4$ one-digit numbers.

If we don't have leading zeroes, then there are three choices for the first digit.  If the first digit is $1$, then we have three choices for the second digit.  Otherwise, four choices.  So, $11$ two-digit numbers (no leading zeroes).

If we allow leading zeroes, we have $15$ two-digit numbers.

For three-digit numbers, the number may consist of one, two, or three different digits.  There are $4$ ways to choose three different digits, $6$ ways to choose two of one and one of another, and $1$ way to choose the same digit for all three places.  Count up the number of arrangements in each case.

You've done the eight-digit number case.  For seven- and six-digit numbers, it's probably easier to count the cases here by *removing* one and two digits from the group, respectively.  For seven-digit numbers, the number of arrangements depends on which digit you remove from the group.

For four- and five-digit numbers, choose your poison.