# Permutations with repeated elements

Tags: combinatorics

Say you have n digits and you want to see how many different numbers you can form with these digits (i.e. all possible numbers, not only the ones that are n digits long). These digits however aren't unique. How would one approach such a question? There wouldn't be any problem if you considered only the numbers that are 8 digits long, but unfortunately that's not the case.

For example: how many numbers can you make with the following 8 digits: $1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0$.

For 8 digits the answer would be quite simple: $\frac{8!}{1!2!3!2!}$

I also figured the answer above includes the answer for 7 and 6 digits because of the two zeros. But I don't know how to continue for 5 etc.. digits.

Comment: Are you allowing leading zeros in your numbers?  It appears so.

Comment: Yeah I figured I'd allow leading zeros to obtain the answer for 7 and 6 digits as well, because a number like $00123233$ would be interpreted as $123233$.

Comment: It won't account for all of the 6 or 7 digit numbers, because the zero could be somewhere in the middle, or on the right end.

Comment: @JLee, you're absolutely right. Then my answer would be $\frac{7*7!}{1!2!3!2!}$ for only the 8 digit numbers. But how to proceed?

Comment: Someone else asked this exact same question yesterday. Is it a contest question?

Comment: @JLee No, it's a regular homework question. Could you send me the link?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048536/how-many-different-numbers-can-you-make-with-the-following-digits